# In questDB retrieve the record which is having the closest to range of timestamps

Tags: sql, questdb

I am new to `QuestDB`, and I think basic `SQL` commands run on it.
I want a scenario where input is 5 timestamps (say `T1`,`T2`,`T3`...`T5`) in a single query I want to get the result from `DB` where `timestamp` is **just-less-than-or-equal-to** `T1`,`T2`,`T3`,`T4` and `T5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have just one row which is smaller than all of the timestamps you can do something like

```
SELECT timestamp FROM table
WHERE timestamp <= '2018-01-01T02:00:00.000000Z' AND 
timestamp <= '2018-01-01T01:01:00.000000Z' AND 
timestamp <= '2018-01-01T02:07:00.000000Z' AND 
timestamp <= '2018-01-01T01:15:00.000000Z' AND 
timestamp <= '2018-01-01T01:11:00.000000Z'
LIMIT -1
```

With `LIMIT -1` you are asking to return only the last of the records, and since in QuestDB the records are sorted by designated timestamp, you will get the closest record that match your conditions.

There is a similar operation that works for joining two tables by closest timestamp. It is call an `ASOF JOIN` and in that case it takes two tables and joins each row from one with the row from the other with closest (equal or earlier) timestamp. If you want strictly earlier timestamp join, you can use the `LT JOIN`.

(Edited after clarification in comments)

You could do an ASOF JOIN with your timestamps by first converting your timestamps into a "pseudo-table" by doing a UNION, then ASOF joining with the table where you have the data. Example below:

```
with times AS (
  (SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT CAST('2023-01-01T02:00:00.000000Z' as timestamp) AS ts FROM long_sequence(1) 
  UNION
  SELECT CAST('2023-01-01T01:01:00.000000Z' as timestamp) AS ts  FROM long_sequence(1) 
  UNION
  SELECT CAST('2023-01-01T02:07:00.000000Z' as timestamp) AS ts FROM long_sequence(1)  
  UNION  
  SELECT CAST('2023-01-01T01:15:00.000000Z' as timestamp) AS ts FROM long_sequence(1)  
  UNION 
  SELECT CAST('2023-01-01T01:11:00.000000Z' as timestamp) AS ts FROM long_sequence(1) 
  ) ORDER BY ts) timestamp(ts)
)
select * from times asof join trades;
```

Note I first define a UNION with the five values, and I indicate the designated timestamp is the `ts` column. With that I can already do ASOF join with any other table where I have a designated timestamp. For each result of the table on the left, I will get the row with equal or closest previous timestamp available.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am looking like to get the closest record for each timestamp, so for T1,T2…T5 I need to return 5 records

Comment: Yep. ASOF JOIN should work for you. I will be back in a few minutes with an example :)

Comment: Edited my answer with the new information

Answer (score 0):

While the approach with ASOF join works, the following should be much faster on large table:

```
select * from 
(
  (select * from trades where timestamp <= '2023-01-01T02:00:00.000000Z' order by timestamp desc limit 1)
  union all 
  (select * from trades where timestamp <= '2023-01-01T01:01:00.000000Z' order by timestamp desc limit 1)
  union all 
  (select * from trades where timestamp <= '2023-01-01T02:07:00.000000Z' order by timestamp desc limit 1)
  union all 
  (select * from trades where timestamp <= '2023-01-01T01:15:00.000000Z' order by timestamp desc limit 1)
  union all 
  (select * from trades where timestamp <= '2023-01-01T01:11:00.000000Z' order by timestamp desc limit 1)
)
```

It's 4.89s vs 0.18s on [questdb demo site](https://demo.questdb.io/) .